# How can the syntax highlighting color differ for words in the same TM Scope?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my C++ code, with some of my syntax highlighting schemes, the typedef `DWORD` is colored differently from the variable it describes, but if I look at the TM scopes for the two, they are both the same:

[image: TM Scope Screenshot]

What black magic is it that controls this behavior? (ultimately, I want to override the blue color in my settings for this theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What causes "DWORD" to have a blue color despite the TextMate Scopes Inspector showing something different?  I think it is a [Decoration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createTextEditorDecorationType), probably applied by an extension you have installed (in my VSCode, "DWORD" is not colored like that, even when windows.h is #included).

Another example of this behavior can be seen with the way "launch.json" files are handled: create a file (anywhere) called "launch.json" and put a few fields into it, including one called "version".  The "version" attribute will be gray, unlike the others, and despite what the TextMate inspector says.  (Incidentally, I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80026) requesting that that gray color be removed.)  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of gray version field in laynch.json]

To confirm this is caused by a decoration, use Help → Toggle Developer Tools, click the "Select an element" icon (default Ctrl+Shift+C), then click on the text of interest.  If you see a class whose name begins with "TextEditorDecorationType", then a decoration has been applied.  Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Developer Tools confirming use of a decoration]

Unfortunately, I do not know how to track down which extension is adding the decoration other than by disabling them individually until it stops happening.

Once you find the one that is causing it, it *may* be themable.  Microsoft has a sample extension called [decorator-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample) that adds a themable decoration.  You may be able to compare how that works to the relevant extension in your case.  Specifically, look in its package.json for a "contributes" containing "colors".

Update 2019-09-04: As Johann noted, the C++ (cpptools) extension [uses Decorations to do semantic highlighting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-c-extension-july-2019-update/), such as highlighting `typedef` names like `DWORD`.  I did not observe that behavior originally because I was using the "Light (Visual Studio)" theme, which does not take advantage of the new capability.  However, the "Light+" and "Dark+" themes (perhaps among others) do.

But, as explained in the linked article, the way these colors are themed is different from how theme colors work elsewhere.  Rather than contributing a named color, the extension parses the active `textMateRules` (from the active theme and any `settings.json` customizations), looking for specific names, then builds decorations accordingly.  So there are multiple layers of exceptional behavior at work here.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - it was the C/C++ tools https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-c-extension-july-2019-update/