# What's causing edited text to have a red background in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

This has been driving me nuts. I'm trying to get to the bottom of what's colorizing edited text in VSCode to take on this red background.

It seems to coincide with my SCM diffs, but behaves oddly e.g. the decoration disappears when I switch editor tabs.

I'm also curious if there are ways to introspect the editor and get to the bottom of this myself if it happens to be some obscure extension interaction.

[image: driving me nuts!]

Comment: try to disable GitLens and see it still happens

Comment: I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57722269/2659307) that talks about diagnosing this sort of thing, but I can already see that it must be due to *some* extension because themes are incapable of setting background colors (only foreground and fontStyle).  I don't recognize that particular decoration though.

Comment: The answer by rioV8 is what worked for me.

Comment: As suggested in the answer, use the extension bisect feature

Answer (score 0):

the problem is happening because of a extension called as trailing spaces, i found it by using [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).
i hope it helps next generation of developers.